# The number of orbits of a (normal) subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to solve the following problem from Dummit & Foote's Abstract Algebra text:

> Assume $G$ acts transitively on the finite set $A$ and let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Let $\mathcal{O}_1,\mathcal{O}_2,\dots, \mathcal{O}_r$ be the distinct orbits of $H$ on $A$.
>
> **(a)** Prove that $G$ permutes the sets $\mathcal{O}_1,\mathcal{O}_2,\dots,\mathcal{O}_r$ in the sense that for each $g \in G$ and each $i \in \{1,\dots,r\}$ there is a $j$ such that $g \mathcal{O}_i=\mathcal{O}_j$, where $g \mathcal{O}=\{g \cdot a \, | \, a \in \mathcal{O}\}$ (i.e., in the notation of Exercise 7 the sets $\mathcal{O}_1,\dots,\mathcal{O}_r$ are blocks). Prove that $G$ is transitive on $\{\mathcal{O}_1,\dots,\mathcal{O}_r\}$. Deduce that all orbits of $H$ on $A$ have the same cardinality.
>
> **(b)** Prove that if $a \in \mathcal{O}_1$ then $|\mathcal{O}_1|=|H: H \cap G_a|$ and prove that $r=|G:HG_a|$. [Draw the sublattice describing the Second Isomorphism Theorem for the subgroups $H$ and $G_a$ of $G$. Note that $H \cap G_a=H_a$.]

---

Here is my attempt:

**(a)** Fix some $g \in G$ and  $i \in \{1,2,\dots,r\}$. Let $\{a_k\}$ be representatives of the orbits $\{\mathcal{O}_k\}$ (so that $\forall k$ $\mathcal{O}_k=H \cdot a_k$) ,and let us denote $g \cdot a_i$ by $a_j$. We have by normality $g \mathcal{O}_i=g H a_i=H g a_i=H a_j=\mathcal{O}_j$.

Since $G$ acts transitively on $A$, given any $a_i,a_j \in A$ we may find an element $g \in G$ with $g \cdot a_i=a_j$, so that $g \mathcal{O}_i=\mathcal{O}_j$.

Since the map $\sigma_g:A \to A$ defined by $\sigma_g(a)=g \cdot a$ is a bijection, restricting it to $\mathcal{O}_i \subseteq A$ gives a bijection $\mathcal{O}_i \to \mathcal{O}_j$, where $\mathcal{O}_j$ is the image $g \mathcal{O_i}$. By transitivity it follows that all orbits have the same cardinality.

**(b)** Since $G$ acts transitively on the set of orbits $\{\mathcal{O}_k\}_{k=1}^r$ we have $r=|G:G_{\mathcal{O}_1}|$. Observe that (where in the following $h$ stands for some element of $H$)
$g \mathcal{O}_1=\mathcal{O}_1 \Leftrightarrow g \cdot a=h \cdot a \Leftrightarrow h^{-1} g \cdot a=a \Leftrightarrow h^{-1}g \in G_a \Leftrightarrow g \in HG_a$.
Thus the proof is complete.

---

My questions regarding this are:

1. Is this proof correct?
2. How is it possible to prove **(b)** using the Second Isomorphism Theorem as described in the hint? I tried to do it but it only worked out if $G$ is finite, in which case I could rewrite indices as quotients of orders.

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you are intended to use $|G_aH:G_a| = |H:H \cap G_a|$ (although I would not describe that as the 2nd Isomorphism Theorem), but your proof looks fine, so I shouldn't worry about it.